# require_once(dompdf/C: mpp\php\PEAR):

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to convert my report.php in pdf using dompdf but I keep getting an error.How can I solve this error please assist. Below is an error I am getting:-

> Warning: require_once(dompdf/C: mpp\php\PEAR): failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\check\dompdf\report.php
>   on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'dompdf/C:
>   mpp\php\PEAR' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\check\dompdf\report.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, but I dont think it works like that

Try this

```
<?php

$fileToConvert = "C:/example/myfile.html"; // Or .php 

if(!file_exists($fileToConvert)) {
    echo "File not found";
    exit;
}

/** Now, We must read php file */
$contentOfFileToConvert = readfile($fileToConvert);

/** Load Dompdf library */
require_once 'C:/libraries/.../dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

/** Reference to Dompdf namespace */
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

/** instantiate and use the dompdf class */
$DOMPDF = new Dompdf();

/** Files Content must be in HTML */
$DOMPDF->loadHtml($contentOfFileToConvert);

/** ... OTHER OPTIONS */
$DOMPDF->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

/** AUTOMATIC DOWNLOAD DIALOG */
$DOMPDF->stream(
    /** Filename that You want */
    'my_document.pdf',
    /**
     * 'compress' = > 1 (=default) or 0:
     *   Apply content stream compression
     *
     * 'Attachment' => 1 (=default) or 0:
     *   Set the 'Content-Disposition:' HTTP header to 'attachment'
     *   (thereby causing the browser to open a download dialog)
     */
    $options = array(
        'compress' => true, //or false
        'attachment' => true //or false
    )
);

/** Options array is not necessary */
$DOMPDF->stream(
    /** Filename that You want */
    'my_document.pdf'
);
```

Comment: Your response is highly appreciate. Please note I have put in the code you provided but I'm still getting an error. below is the error I got. Please assist

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''attachment'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\check\dompdf\report.php on line 56

Comment: Line 56 --->   'attachment' => true //or false

Comment: @BakangTefo --- 1. comma missing near first true. I edited it. Try now --- 2. Options array is not necessary

Comment: its working, but it says file not found, however, I included the right path to convert a my webpage (report.php) as pdf. It's really frustrating.

Comment: Because you need to use Double Slash. Instead of C:/Path/file.php use C:\\Path\\file.php or try C://Path//file.php